# Pass array to Partial in Hugo framework

Tags: html, hugo

I would create a Partial that take array of strings.

In Front Matter section:

```
---
title: Développeur
typedjstitle: ["Front-end", "Back-end", "Fullstack"]
endtitle: Sénior
description: Passionné du développement web.
---
```

then in my `layouts`

```
<div class="intro">
  <h1>
    {{ .Title }} {{ partial "typedjs.html" .Typedjstitle }}{{ .Endtitle
    }}{{ if .Site.Params.addDot }}<span class="dot">.</span>{{ end }}
  </h1>
  <div class="intro-content">{{ .Content }}</div>
</div>
```

In my Partial

```
<h1 id="typed-title"></h1>
{{ $strings := . }}
<script>
  var typed = new Typed("#typed-title", {
    strings: $strings,
    typeSpeed: 100,
    loop: true,
    cursorChar: "_",
  });
</script>
```

I'm getting this error:

> execute of template failed at <.Typedjstitle>: can’t evaluate field
> Typedjstitle in type page.Page

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
{{ partial "typedjs.html" . }}
```

And then in Partial you have access to page .Params

```
<h1 id="typed-title"></h1>
{{ $strings := .Params.typedjstitle }}

{{ range $strings }}
<p>{{ . }}</p>
{{ end }}
```